# ios: Naming views through loops

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Just wondering how i can dynamically name Uiviews or variables in general and then reference them in Obj C(X code), and once created the best way to reference them.

I read somewhere else that you should define the list in an array and then create, but the problem is that my users number is dynamic.

```
 for(int x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
 {
   UIView *"User_"&(x) = [[UIView Alloc] init];
   User_x.frame = CGRectMake( 10 * x , 10 , 10 ,10);
 }
```

What is the best way to approach doing something like this?

Comment: I prescribe school and lessons.

Comment: Unfortunately i work full time in another field, so can't go to school. I'm slowly learning thanks to tutorials and the kindness of others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project has `ARC=Yes`, the compiler will delete reference foreach cycle of your view.
However you can add a tag on your views:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= 10; x++) 
{
    UIView *user = [[UIView Alloc] init];
    user.tag=x;
    User.frame = CGRectMake( 10 * x , 10 , 10 ,10);
    [yourSuperView addSubview:user];
}
```

Comment: How do i then reference say user 5?

if  i wanted to then do: 
    `[User.5 setBackgroundColor:[UIColour whiteColor]];`

Comment: use method "viewWithTag"

Comment: [[yourSuperView viewWithTag:5] setBackgroundColor[UIColour whiteColor]];

Comment: Thanks Matt. I will give this a shot. Only wondering what my major concerns are when i delete and add new users.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this

```
 NSMutableArray *viewArr= [@[] mutableCopy];
 for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
 {
   UIView *view = [[UIView Alloc] init];
   view.frame = CGRectMake( 10 * x , 10 , 10 ,10);
   [viewArr addObject:view];
 }
```

Comment: How do i then reference say user 5?

if  i wanted to then do: 
    `[User.5 setBackgroundColor:[UIColour whiteColor]];`